# Which method should I use for accessing files and why?

Tags: python, file

I am in python and there is a lot of ways to access files.

***Method 1:***

```
fp = open("hello.txt", "w")
fp.write("No no no");
fp.close()

fp = open("hello.txt", "r")
print fp.read()
fp.close()
```

***Method 2:***

```
open("hello.txt", "w").write("hello world!")
print open("hello.txt", "r").read()
```

***Method 3:***

```
with open("hello.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Yes yes yes")

with open("hello.txt") as f:
    print f.read()
```

Is there a specific advantage in using each of these?

Stuff I know:

- Method 2 and Method 3 closes the file automatically, but
  Method 1 doesn't.
- Method 2 doesn't give you a handle to do multiple operations.

Comment: I am looking for reasons, I prefer 3rd one too...

Comment: Method 3 handels also exceptions and closes automatically the file.

Comment: @Themerius What do you mean by `handles exceptions`? Method 2 also closes the file automatically.

Comment: @ATOzTOA It just so happens to close the file - but the language specification doesn't say that *has* to happen

Comment: "with" rocks. Use it a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the third method.

There is a common pattern in programming where to use some object you have set it up, run your code, and tear it down again. File handles are one example of this: you have to open the file, run your code, *and then close the file*. This last is not optional -- it's important for the operating system to know that you are done with it, and for Python to flush all the data out of its IO buffers.

Now, CPython is a reference counted language. That means that it counts how many pieces of code 'know about' a given object, so that when that count becomes zero it can clean up said object and reuse its space in memory. In method 2, the reference count of the file object becomes zero, which allows Python to clean it up. And file objects' cleanup method  also closes them. However, you should in general not rely on this -- reference counting is an implementation detail of the standard version of Python, and there's no guarantee that whatever you're using to run the program will do the same. That's why you shouldn't use method 2.

Method 1 is better, because you explicitly close the file -- as long as you *reach* the `.close()` function call! If an exception was thrown in the middle of that code block, the `close` would not be reached, and the file would not be explicitly closed. So you should really wrap the middle code in a `try... finally` block.

Method 3 is therefore best: you use the `with` statement -- an idiomatic way of enclosing the `.close` in a `finally` block -- to close the file, so you don't have to worry about the extra syntactic fluff of `try... except`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this, kind of extended version of `method 3`:

```
with open("hello.txt","w+") as f:  
    f.write("Yes yes yes")
    f.seek(0)                  #places the cursor back to the start of the file
    print f.read()             #now read the file
```

Advantages:

> 1. It opens the file only once
> 2. w+ mode allows both read and write on the same file object
> 3. `with` takes care of the closing of file

Comment: (I am not the downvoter), I believe your reply is not answering OP's question, digressing out from the original problem, and solving a context which was not intended here

Answer (score 0):

I would think it is best to go method one as it is explicit and you can surround it with a `try` and `except block` or the method 3